# maximum value of a row with NA -- unix

Tags: unix, awk, row, max

I have a set of `.csv` files with known number of columns that contains `NA` as entry as well as values.

I would like to get the maximum value of each row and then calculate the average of all the max values.

Input file:

```
"V1","V2","V3"
10,15,20
20,NA,5
NA,NA,NA
10,5,6
```

Comment: and what's your desired output?

Comment: @dogbane: ideally I want a value which is the average of maximum values of all rows; where the average is `(sum of maximum values/number of row that actually have a value)` --- so cant put the NA as 0

Comment: So do you want the average a `20+20+0+10/4` or `20+20+10/3`?

Comment: @sudo-O: the average of `20+20+10/3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum values:

```bsh
# Display 0 for NA rows
awk -F, 'NR>1{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>a&&$i!="NA")a=$i;print a}' file
20
20
0
10

# Display nothing for NA rows 
awk -F, 'NR>1&&/[0-9]/{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>a&&$i!="NA")a=$i;print a}' file
20
20
10
```

With average:

```bsh
# Counting NA rows 
awk -F, 'NR>1{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>a&&$i!="NA")a=$i;s+=a;print a}END{print s/(NR-1)}' file
20
20
0
10
12.5

# Ignoring NA rows
awk -F, 'NR>1&&/[0-9]/{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>a&&$i!="NA")a=$i;s+=a;c++;print a}END{print s/c}' file
20
20
10
16.6667
```

Comment: `/[0-9]/` means only apply the block to lines containing a digit. So it skips over lines just containing `NA`.

Comment: You initialise `a` to `0`. This solution won't work correctly if the file has negative numbers.

Comment: @dogbane means if the line is `-1 -20 -50` the max would be displayed as `0` how should negative numbers be handled?

Comment: I dont have negative number

Comment: @V-V then you don't need to worry about dogbane's comment. In future provide the correct format from the start. Does this answer your question, if so please upvote and accept otherwise edit your question to describe clearly the output expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{max=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!~/NA/&&$i>max){max=$i;}count+=max;print max}END{print count/NR}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
>cat temp
10 15 20
20 NA 5
NA NA NA
10 5 6
> awk '{max=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i!~/NA/&&$i>max){max=$i;}count+=max;print max}END{print count/NR}' temp
20
20
0
10
12.5
>
```

Comment: What is point in adding an identically solution 30 minutes after mine? Your answer adds nothing?